# Select rows where Column1 is alphanumeric

Tags: r

I also need rows with Count>0.  I can do it in a separate step but but I am curious if I can combine those 2 conditions in single step.

I want to drop those 2 records with ? and _ from my result set.

```
Type = c("alpha","bravo","charlie","?","_", "delta")
 Count = c(1,2,3,4,5,0) 
 Desc = c("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","ccc", "ddd") 
 df = data.frame(Desc, Type,Count)       # df is a data frame

 df[df$Type %in% [a:z],]   ##  this doesn't work
```

Comment: Try `df[grep('[A-Za-z]+', df$Type),]`

Comment: I also see that I got <Type> as a factor, which is even more interesting.

Comment: use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the data.frame.  By default, it will be `TRUE`, so character columns are converted to factors.

Comment: Thansk, Arkun !!! problem solved, it works even on factors,   I tried to play making > "a" and greater sign didn't work on factors.       Yours works anywhere.

Comment: Improve wording and spell out partial words.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
df[grep('[A-Za-z]+', df$Type),]
```

Or

```
df[grep('^[^[:punct:]]+$', df$Type),]
```